# How do i catch a syntaxerror exception of the great class exception contained within the java classes in Java?

Tags: java, syntax, syntax-error, try-catch

I'm trying to put a syntax error in my code, however whenever i compile, it will not run, how can I force the compiler to compile with a syntax error using annotations or try-catch statements.

Comment: That is not how anything works. If you have a syntax error you cannot compile your code - period. And if you cannot compile it then you cannot run it.

Answer (score 3):

Quite simple: you don't. If the compiler can't/won't compile it, you can't run it (the reason being is the [compiler can't understand what you wrote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_error)).